Page Size Error Loading Bigquery table into R Studio
Using the bq_table_download() function to download a table that has only 408,000 rows. Seems way to small to be getting a page size error, but this is the error message I get.
Downloading first chunk of data.
Received 57,851 rows in the first chunk.
Downloading the remaining 349,733 rows in 9 chunks of (up to) 43,388 rows.
Error: 407584 rows were requested, but only 392485 rows were received.
Leave page_size unspecified or use an even smaller value.
Below is the code I tried:
#this gave the page_size error originally
table_name <- bq_table_download(tb)

#so I gave this one a try
table_name <- bq_table_download(tb, page_size=NULL, start_index = 0L, max_connections = 6L, n_max = Inf) 


Hi @dariane, Have a look at this GitHub issue. this might be helpful in your case.

Hi @dariane, If my answer addressed your question, do consider accepting and upvoting it as per Stack Overflow guidelines, helping more Stack contributors with their research. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

As mentioned in this similar GitHub issue, if you are running into this issue, you can try creating a wrapper function around bq_table_download that catches failing downloads, reduces the page size and retries the download. Hence you can resolve the error.
You can also file a bug in the Issue Tracker if the issue still persists.
